# Parsing user input to call the correct Overloaded Function

Tags: c++, c, parsing, overloading

(new to c++/c) I'm trying to create a function that parses the user input and calls the correct overloaded function.

I have three overloaded functions, one has a parameter of double, one has a parameter of char*, and the last has a parameter of int array[5]...

I'm unsure how to determine what data type is being passed in, so I thought maybe you can tell by formatting codes.. doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
void parseUserInput(char *userInput)
{
    if (userInput == "%c")
    {
        printf(">> This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(char *) >> function ...");
        assessGrade((char)userInput);
    }
    else if (userInput == "%f")
    {
        double temp = atof(userInput);
        printf(">> This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(double) >> function ...");
        assessGrade(temp);

    }
    else if (userInput == "%d")
    {
        printf("This input should be directed to the << assessGrade(int[]) >> function ...");
        assessGrade((int)userInput);
    }
}



int main(void)
{
    int infiniteLoop = 0;

    char* input = (char*)malloc(100);
    

    while (infiniteLoop != 1)
    {
        printf("Enter Student's Grade(s) >>> ");
        fgets(input, 100, stdin);

        parseUserInput(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: In C you cannot compare strings with `if (userInput == "%c")`, please use `strcmp()`. And casting a `char*` to `char` with `assessGrade((char)userInput)` is bad.

Comment: Can't do it in C++ either. Most reasonable solution is to either do what Weather Vane suggests above or replace the `char *` with `std::string` and then go through the rest of the program and use C++ idioms.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you. As `strcmp()` compares two strings, how would you compare to determine if the input was int, double, or char? Would I make three new variables inside of `parseUserInput()` of each data type, and use that for the comparison?

Comment: In C there is no overloading. You should pass another argument to specify the type.

Comment: Only thing you can do is read as string and then test to see if the string meets the requirements to be a `float` (all digits and there's a dot) or `int` (all digits, no dot). Remember that a user could typo or deliberately input garbage at any time, so even if you're expecting a particular type you might not get it.

Comment: But then you still have a problem - is "1234" *intended* to be a string, or an integer?

Comment: @user4581301 How would you determine if there was a dot? Would it look something like this -- `if (userInput > 0 && userInput< 100) && userInput != dot)`

Comment: You can attempt to convert the whole string into an `int` with a function like `strtol`. If it fails, use `strtod` to see if it an be parsed into a floating point number. If that fails... well, looks like you have a string.